# ItemAdd - SalesAndPurchaseMod aggregate when item is not reimbursable

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am getting the following error when adding items through IPP:

```
There was an error when modifying a ItemNonInventory.  Cannot use SalesAndPurchaseMod aggregate when the item is not reimbursable.
```

The error has been slowing adding up in SyncActivity:

```
"NgObjectType" => "Item",
"OperationType" => "ItemAdd",
"SyncMessageCode" => "3170",
"SyncMessage" => "There was an error when modifying a ItemNonInventory.  Cannot use SalesAndPurchaseMod aggregate when the item is not reimbursable. "
```

An explanation of the error would be perfect. Interested in what is causing it. Is there a way to avoid this or to not cause this error?

EDIT:
Looking through my requests, I'm not really seeing the entity IDs and I can't seem to pull up the requests so I'm wonder if these were requests while QB was acting off the other day or a mistake on my part. Instead the question should be:

**What is the meaning of the above error and what might cause it? I'm unsure of where the SalesAndPurchaseMod comes into play as I'm not the one writing the QBXML to QBD.**

Comment: Can you post the XML request you send to IPP?

Comment: The problem is that there are about 100 cases where that error message can come up... and about 98 of them are undocumented. Without seeing the requests you're sending, you probably won't get an answer. My *guess* would be that you're specifying an invalid or missing account in your request.

Answer (score 0):

Try SalesOrPurchaseMod when you sync the info. In QuickBooks' items and services tab, the item has a checkbox that says it is used for a certain job. That must be checked to use SalesAndPurchaseMod.

Comment: If I had the choice to choose a certain QBXML request, I would. The issue is that an update from QBD web services does not update the item correctly (from what I can tell). I will change any of that based on the [XML schema](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Item) if possible, but it doesn't look like I am able to.